# IBM Worklight - How to remove JSONStore resources from the application

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore, worklight-studio

I am not using JSONStore in my App and as it comes as a package by default within WL App. Is there any option to remove them, even manually on a particular platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Worklight 6.0.0.x this can be achieved,

- In Android: by removing the `<features>` section in application-descriptor.xml
- In iOS: by deleting deleting native\Frameworks\sqlcipher.framework (to be improved in the future)

In Worklight 5.0.x.x this is done manually,

- In Android: by deleting the file native\assets\www\icudt46l.zip
- In iOS: by deleting the framework native\Frameworks\sqlcipher.framework